# Vue js filter not compatible on some mobile device

Tags: javascript, vue.js, compatibility

Am using vue js on my webview app only to filter user search for now. Everything is working very fine till i run my app on `Samsung SM-G530H`, i get an error saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`, i have checked everything correct and it work on other device except older device. Please how do make it compatible in all device?

[image]

```
new Vue({
      el: '#SearchVueContenPage',
        data() {
            return {
                q: '',
                total_result: 0,
                searchProduct: null,
                loading: false,
                sort_filter: ``,
                URL: ajax_appserver("public", "_api/searchProduct.php")
            }
        },

        computed: {
            search() {
              if (!this.searchProduct) {
                return []
              }

              if (!this.q) {
                  this.total_result = 0;
                return this.searchProduct.recent.slice(0,4);
              }
              var query = this.q.toLowerCase();
              var searchResult = this.searchProduct.result.filter(row => row.product_name.toLowerCase().includes(query) || row.business_name.toLowerCase().includes(query));
              this.total_result = searchResult.length;
              return searchResult;
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.loading = true;
            this.fetchData().then(() => {
             this.loading = false
            });
        },

        methods: {
            sortStatus: function(status) {
                   this.sort_filter = status;
             },

            async fetchData() {

                ajax_fetch(this.URL).then(json => {
                    this.searchProduct = json;
                    Vue.nextTick(function(){
                        //Store object in IndexDb
                    }.bind(this));
                });
            }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the error is happening because you are trying to run code that uses "Method definitions" syntax.

[Method definitions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

**The reason** you are getting the error is that "Method definitions" is a relatively new feature/syntax in JS and not supported by all browsers.

**The solution** for that will be to precompile the code to ES5 using babel.
If you are using VUE-CLI you already have webpack and you just need to configure it to output ES5 code.

Comment: "precompile the code to ES5 using babel" how do i do this, is there any online tool to help me?

Comment: how do you execute your code? do you use 'vue-cli'?

Comment: I did it here https://babeljs.io, but i still get an error `ReferenceError {stack: (...), message: "regeneratorRuntime is not defined"} `

Comment: I include the vue.js javascript library on my page and write my code, is there any other better way i can execute it?

Comment: The "right" way is either generate an app using vue-cli (you can read in the docs how to do it) or pass all your code through babel.